MerchantDisplayName in Stripe Elements
I have a marketplace application where customers place orders with merchants. Merchants have connected accounts in Stripe in which they receive their payouts. When a customer places an order on React Native, we can show the merchant's business name by doing something like this:
   await initPaymentSheet({
       merchantDisplayName: merchantName,
       ...
   });

However, when using the @stripe/react-stripe-js library in React.JS to build a custom web checkout flow using <Elements />, there is no way to pass this merchant name. When customer pay using Apple Pay, it shows the incorrect name. For example, a store might be called "Billy's Bike Shop", but the Stripe Connected Account is under "Billy Joseph".
In this case, when a customer chooses to pay using Apple Pay on web, it'll say "Pay Billy Joseph", when it should say "Pay Billy's Bike Shop". This functionality is achieved on mobile using the initPaymentSheet function above in @stripe/stripe-react-native, but it is not available in React? Am I missing something?
Thanks
Update based on comment: I understand it's a different component. What I'm saying is, on mobile, there's clearly a way to override the connected account's business information with a customer display-able name. I am not sure why we wouldn't be able to do that on web as well.

PaymentSheet on mobile (ReactNative/iOS/Android) is a different component than  the React integration on web, hence they have different settings. On the React integration on web, it's the Stripe's PaymentElement and it probably takes the Connected Account's business information directly, so you might want to update those information on the Connected Account.
I would recommend writing to Stripe Support and they could help on checking the current information and how to update the Connected Account.

Yes, I understand it's a different component. What I'm saying is, on mobile, there's clearly a way to override the connected account's business information with a customer display-able name. I am not sure why we wouldn't be able to do that on web as well.
Having the connected account update their business information doesn't make any sense as we operate with standard connect accounts, which would require us to contact all of our merchants and update their information.

Yeah would be a good feedback to Stripe Support

You have a valid point but seems like Stripe React JS library designed this way for some reason, maybe noone ever thought about that or there are other reasons such as Stripe guidelines.
I would encourage you to open an issue on Github issue page of that package here. That seems to be a more accurate place to find an answer or get it added as Feature Request in future versions.
